# Method does not override another method View.OnClickListener (Error in Override)

Tags: android, overriding, onclicklistener

I m trying to create a new java file for button (sin) as this is about calculator. But it is showing `Error` in second override annotations. (Method does not override method from its SuperClass). There is one more `Error` associating with brackets in the bottom part of code. Being newbie this is the first time I'm having my hands on this part of java. I have searched many of the sites but didn't found any solution. Any help will be appreciated.

**SinglesinActivity.java**

```
package com.marsh.calculator.calculator;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class SinglesinActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnsin);

        b.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onclick(View v) {
        int id = v.getId();
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.btnsin:
                break;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: "onClick()", not "onclick()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `onClick` not `onclick`. 
Make the following changes:

```
@Override public void onClick(View v) { 
    int id = v.getId(); 
    switch (id) { 
        case R.id.btnsin: break; 
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a typo. change onclick to onClick.